# EWS Basic/NTLM Authentication

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, basic-authentication, exchangewebservices, ntlm

I'm currently trying to send a SOAP request to an Exchange server, but I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized. I repeated the request using Postman, and it looks like it's trying to do NTLM authentication. However, I want to authenticate using Basic authentication by using just a username/password. Is there any way to specify this in the message headers or something? Is this something that's configured on the server end?

If it's not possible, how do I go about implementing NTLM authentication? I'm very new to this, so any help/direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It needs to be configured in the Exchange server. You cannot simply ask the server for a less secure authentication method. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection2